# Jax-rs and amqp zipkin integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I've been roaming the depths of the internet but I find myself unsatisfied by the examples I've found so far. Can someone point me or, show me, a good starting point to integrate zipkin tracing with jaxrs clients and amqp clients?

My scenario is quite simple and I'd expect this task to be trivial tbh. We have a micro services based architecture and it's time we start tracing our requests and have global perspective of our inter service dependencies and what the requests actually look like (we do have metrics but I want more!) . The communication is done via jax-rs auto generated clients and we use rabbit template for messaging.

I've seen brave integrations with jaxrs but they are a bit simplistic. My zipkin server is a spring boot mini app using stream-rabbit, so zipkin data is sent using rabbitmq.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no out of the box solution for now for either of these cases. You can find the AMQP instrumentation discussion here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176907/integrating-spring-cloud-sleuth-with-spring-boot-amqp . I'm in touch with one of the devs to get the PR with instrumentation. As for the JaxRS clients you can use Brave - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/Using+OpenZipkin+Brave . We will be working on a bridge between Sleuth and Brave one day but it's not there yet. Hopefully that's useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with Marcin Grzejszczak and Adrien Cole (zipkin and sleuth creators/active developers) I ended up creating a Jersey filter that acts as bridge between sleuth and brave. Regarding AMQP integration, added a new @StreamListener with a conditional for zipkin format spans (using headers). Sending messages to the sleuth exchange with zipkin format will then be valid and consumed by the listener. For javascript (zipkin-js), I ended up creating a new AMQP Logger that sends zipkin spans to a determined exchange. If someone ends up reading this and needs more detail, you're welcome to reach out to me.